# How to add all Data from Access

Tags: java

I want to add all data from my MS Access database table when I click on Add button. But when I Click on add Button it just displays a first single record from the table. Kindly anyone can help me how to fix this issue. it works fine when I click on Add button did not show any error but it displays only one record in JTable I want to display all records from MS access database.

```
  import java.awt.Color;
  import java.awt.Font;
  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
  import javax.swing.JButton;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
  import javax.swing.JTable;
  import javax.swing.JTextField;
  import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
  import java.sql.*;

   public class JTableRow {

public static void main(String[] args){

    // create JFrame and JTable
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    final JTable table = new JTable();


    Object[] columns = {"Id","Doctor Name","Specialization","Visit Day"};
    final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    model.setColumnIdentifiers(columns);


    table.setModel(model);


    table.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    table.setForeground(Color.black);
    Font font = new Font("",1,22);
    table.setFont(font);
    table.setRowHeight(30);





    JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add");

    btnAdd.setBounds(150, 220, 100, 25);


    // create JScrollPane
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
    pane.setBounds(0, 0, 880, 200);

    frame.setLayout(null);

    frame.add(pane);


    frame.add(btnAdd);


    final Object[] row = new Object[4];

    btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


            try{
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                String url="jdbc:odbc:employeedsn";
                Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url);
                Statement s = con.createStatement();

                String st = "select * from doctors";
                s.execute(st);
                ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet();
                while((rs!=null) && (rs.next())){

                    row[0] = rs.getString("id");;
                    row[1] = rs.getString("Dname");;
                    row[2] = rs.getString("spec");
                    row[3] = rs.getString("visitDay");

                    // add a row to the model

                        model.addRow(row);

                    break;
                }
                con.close();
            }
            catch(Exception sqlEx) {
                System.out.println(sqlEx);

            }

        }
    });

    frame.setSize(900,400);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

Comment: Hint: don't put together your building blocks before they work on their. In order to debug you database retrieval simply drop all gui stuff. Write a minimal piece of code that just prints your data. Get that to work before making things more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a break statement after model.addRow(row):

```
                // add row to the model

                    model.addRow(row);

                break; // breaks out of the while() { } loop.
```

Break will exit the current block of code (or more if nested in multiple fors/whiles/dos). This means it completely stops and breaks out of the while loop you have after executing once. Remove the break; line and allow it to run more than once

Comment: Thank you so much abelito! Its working fine now. I am crazy i did not notice break statement. Thank you once again.